# evernote api: example of php code to retrieve the text of a note

Tags: php, evernote

I look for an example of PHP code to retrieve the text of a note on the Evernote server.

So far, I only found trivial examples listing the notebooks, and helping to get authenticated. But all the references are for Java and not for PHP, and nothing lists the notes self.

I understand I have to use the function findNotesMetaData but I don't understand what to specify as fourth argument.

I need some help to get further. I don't know enough Java to understand the equivalent statement in PHP. Thanks in advance.

Pierre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get note contents with findNotesMetaData. Here's simple code snippet for getting notes (also refer to the sample on github to know how to get token with OAuth).

```
 use EDAM\NoteStore\NoteFilter;
 use Evernote\Client;
 $client = new Client(array(
     'token' => $accessToken,
     'sandbox' => true
 ));
 $filter = new NoteFilter();
 $filter->words = "Evernote";
 $notes = $client->getNoteStore()->findNotes($filter, 0, 10);
```

You can see more details about searching notes [here](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/searching_notes.php).

Comment: I had to change the line "$filter = new NoteFilter();" into "$filter = new \EDAM\NoteStore\NoteFilter();" to get it working

Comment: Is it possible to search notes by date?

Comment: It's possible. You can see the search grammer here: http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/search_grammar.php

Answer (score 0):

On github there is PHP Evernote API SDK

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-php

Comment: Indeed, that is the only example I ever found on the web and it is the trivial one I spoke about. Is there no other snippet of PHP code about Evernote on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Not PHP, but the perl answer for this is as follows:

```
use strict;
use Net::Evernote::Simple;

my $evernote = Net::Evernote::Simple->new(
   # Obtain a developer token from Evernote and put it here
   dev_token => 'YOUR DEV TOKEN HERE',
);

warn "Evernote API version out of date!\n" if( ! $evernote->version_check() ); # check if our client API version still works

my $note_store = $evernote->note_store() or die "getting notestore failed: $@";

my $notebooks = $note_store->listNotebooks( $evernote->dev_token() ) or die "oops:$!"; # retrieve all of our notebooks.  See https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/ for other things you can do.

for my $notebook ( @$notebooks ) {
  print "evernote->note_store->listNotebooks: " . $notebook->guid() . "\t" . $notebook->name(), "\n";
  $arg{'guid'}=$notebook->guid() if($notebook->name() eq 'Some Notebook Name');
}

my $tags = $note_store->listTags( $evernote->dev_token() ) or die "oops:$!";

for my $s ( @$tags ) {
   print "evernote->note_store->listTags: " . $s->guid() . "\t" .  $s->name(), "\n";
}

use Data::Dumper; print Data::Dumper->Dump([ $notebooks ],['$notebooks']); 

my $srch = Net::Evernote::Simple::EDAMNoteStore::NoteFilter->new() or die "oops:$!";
$srch->notebookGuid( $arg{'guid'} ) or warn "hmm: $!";
# $srch->inactive( 1 ); # set this to go through the trash
print Data::Dumper->Dump([ $srch ],['$srch']);

my $res=Net::Evernote::Simple::EDAMNoteStore::NotesMetadataResultSpec->new();
                #   $authenticationToken, $filter, $offset, $maxNotes, $resultSpec);
my $sr = $note_store->findNotesMetadata(  $evernote->dev_token(), $srch, 0, 99999, $res) or die "oops:$!";

print Data::Dumper->Dump([ $res ],['$res']);
print Data::Dumper->Dump([ $sr ],['$sr']);

                                #($authenticationToken, $guid, $withContent, $withResourcesData, $withResourcesRecognition, $withResourcesAlternateData);
my $note = $note_store->getNote( $evernote->dev_token(), 'some_note_GUID_here', 1, 1, 1, 1) or die "oops:$!";

print Data::Dumper->Dump([ $note ],['$note']);

my $tags = $note_store->listTags( $evernote->dev_token() ) or die "oops:$!";

print Data::Dumper->Dump([ $tags ],['$tags']);
```